# Subspace clustering with random transformation

Tags: data-mining, linear-algebra, classification, cluster

One approach for clustering a high dimensional dataset is to use linear transformation, and the most common approaches are PCA and random projection (where random projection arises from the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma). I was wondering why we can't use other random transformation  s like when our transformation matrix $R$ was drawn from a uniform distribution?

Comment: Johnson–Lindenstrauss random projections (there are by now several different algorithms) approximately preserve distances. Other random transformations might not.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that choosing $R$ according to a uniform distribution *with zero mean* constitutes a Johnson–Lindenstrauss random projection (i.e., it approximately preserves distances). See for example a [paper](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~optas/papers/jl.pdf) by Achlioptas which suggests three distributions that definitely work: a zero-mean Gaussian, a random $\pm 1$, and a specific distribution on $\{0,\pm 1\}$. It is probable that using the methods in the paper, the case of the uniform distribution can also be analyzed.